# D.C. al Fine with standard repeats

Tags: theory, repeats

I have a question regarding *D.C. al Fine* with standard repeats. Let me try to explain this with an example.

Let's say I need to chart out a piece of music. Upon listening to the music, this is the structure:

1. There are 8 measures of music, with the second half (measure 5-8) the same as the first
2. Followed by 5 measures of unique music
3. Followed by 8 measures of music similar to 1

So, what I'm thinking when it comes to charting this down is:

1. Chart the first 4 measures (1-4) and add a standard repeat open at 1 and close at 4, so that the 4 measures will be played twice
2. Chart the next 5 measures (5-9)
3. Add a *D.C. al Fine* at the end of measure 9, and add *Fine* at end of measure 4

My question is: When we go back to the start once we reach *D.C. al Fine*, will we still play the standard repeats or do we only play through it once?

Answer (score 3):

Okay I've found the answer:  We have to add *con rep.* if we want to include nested repetitions, or *senza rep.* if we do not (though by convention *D.C. al Fine* defaults to *D.C. al Fine senza rep.*)

Comment: That's fine in 18th century classical writing.  If you're writing a pop song today.there are no set conventions and your audience won't understand 'senza rep.'

Answer (score 2):

The 'no repeats after a DC' convention applies to the early Classical style, particularly in suites of dance-style movements, the presecessor of the symphony.  It has connections to the convention of enclosing the Exposition, but not the Recapitulation of a Sonata form movement in repeats.  There is dispute over whether this repeat in e.g. a Beethoven piano sonata is to be actually played, or whether it is merely a structural convention.

It is unlikely a modern 'classical' piece will use a DC, unless consciously emulationg an older style.  A pop song might.  You need to state 'make repeat on DC' or 'no repeat on DC'.  It's also common to see 1st, 2nd and 3rd X endings to the first verse of a song, with an indication to proceed to the middle 8 after the 2nd ending, to the coda - possibly a repeat chorus with a key lift - after the 3rd.    State what you want in plain English.